# ng-options with a dynamic expression is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I'm trying to create a `directive` in angular, to replace the regular dropdown. I need to be able to set a dynamic expression to `ng-options` but doesn't seem to be working inside the directive.

It works perfectly outside it.

This is the directive

```
angular.module('app.dropdown',[])

.directive('swDropdown',[  function ( ){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template:'<div><select  ng-model="swModel" ng-options="{{expression}}"  ></div>',
        link: link,
        scope:{
            swOptions:"=",
            swLabel:'@',
            swValue:'@',
            swModel:"="
        }
    };

    function link (scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.defaultText = angular.isDefined(attrs.swDefaultText)?attrs.swDefaultText:'Choose';
         scope.selected = scope.defaultText;
         scope.expression = 'item as item.name for item in swOptions';


    }
}]);
```

Controller example:

```
angular.module('app',['app.dropdown']).controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.model="";
        $scope.expression = 'item as item.name for item in options';
        $scope.options = [
          {id:1,name:'hola'},
          {id:2,name:'chau'}]
      });
```

Html:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    Working dropdown<br/>
    <select ng-model="model" ng-options="{{expression}}"></select>
    <br/>
    Not working inside a directive
    <sw-dropdown  sw-model="model" sw-options="options"></sw-dropdown>
  </body>
```

[This is the example](http://plnkr.co/edit/bxpKp3zwnYlqrKsRZ6ei?p=preview)

Any clue about why it is not working?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good question, but I suggest including the **relevant** parts of the code in the question itself. The question must be self-sustaining even if the link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question. At the end of the day, `ng-options` needs to have a value when `<select>` is being processed by Angular.

1) You can either set it up in the "pre-link" function:

```
.directive('swDropdown',[function (){
   return {
     ...
     link: {
         pre: function(scope){
            scope.expression = "item as item.name for item in swOptions";
         },
         post: // your normal link function
     }
   }
}]);
```

2) Or, if you are lazy, you could just add `ng-if="expression"` to the template, and keep everything the same:

```
.directive('swDropdown',[function (){
   return {
     ...
     template: '<div><select ng-if="expression" ng-model="swModel" ng-options="{{expression}}"></select></div>',
     link: link // this is treated as post-link
   }

   function link(scope, element){
     // ...
   }
}]);
```

3) if your expression is truly needs to be mutable and modifyable (seems like a weird case and should probably be address with a more suitable ViewModel), then you'd need to force re-compilation:

```
function link(scope, element){
   ...
   scope.changeExpression = function(newExpression){
     scope.expression = newExpression;

     // $compile should be injected into your directive's function
     $compile(element)(scope);
   }
}
```

Btw, just adding `$compile(element)(scope);` to your current link function would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NewDev, the `$compile(element)(scope)` did the magic!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have an isolated scope and thus ngOptions does not feed in this value properly

Change ur template to

```
template:'<div><select  ng-model="swModel" ng-options="item as item.name for item in swOptions"></div>',
```

Edit: if you really want to pass a node you need to do it in the compile function because thats when the ngOptions directive compiles them.

```
angular.module('app.dropdown',[])

.directive('swDropdown',[  function ( ){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template:'<div><select  ng-model="swModel" ng-options="{{expression}}"  ></div>',
        compile: compile,
        scope:{
            swOptions:"=",
            swLabel:'@',
            swValue:'@',
            swModel:"="
        }
    };

    function compile(cElement, cAttributes, transclude){
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs){
          scope.expression = 'item as item.name for item in swOptions';
        },
        post: function(scope, element, attrs){
          scope.defaultText = angular.isDefined(attrs.swDefaultText)?attrs.swDefaultText:'Choose';
          scope.selected = scope.defaultText;
        }
      }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Yang-li but that doesn't answer my question, I'm looking for a dynamic way of setting the ng-options, and there you are actually "hardcoding" it.

Comment: Well your scope.expression is hardcoded into a variable that isn't mutable... What I've provided you is not any less dynamic than what you had before

Comment: Yes, but that line is the one that will change. I just didn't add the code to do it, and wasn't so clear with it. Anyways thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Well i editted my answer to incorporate what u wanted although it may not be the most semantic answer for ur case, it certainly can be useful in generate